# Какой метод возвращает семейное положение пользователя

Tags: vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте, в документации не нашел такой метод, прошу помочь!

Нужно, чтобы я передал программе id и она возвращала семейное положение данного пользователя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ознакомьтесь с документацией **VK API** внимательнее:

https://vk.com/dev/users.get

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод `users.get`, параметр `fields=relation`, полная query **GET**-запроса:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=XXXX&fields=relation&v=5.65
```

Ответ от ВК:

```
{"response":[{"id":XXXX,"first_name":"Name","last_name":"Lastname","relation":0}]}
```

Типы **relations**:

> семейное положение пользователя. Возможные значения: 
>   1 — не женат/не замужем; 
>   2 — есть друг/есть подруга; 
>   3 — помолвлен/помолвлена; 
>   4 — женат/замужем; 
>   5 — всё сложно; 
>   6 — в активном поиске; 
>   7 — влюблён/влюблена; 
>   8 — в гражданском браке; 
>   0 — не указано.